# Is it okay to insert an <iframe> into the page's content?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Using a content script, I plan to insert a UI into the page in an `<iframe>`, but I have a few concerns.

- Do people commonly use settings/extensions to block `iframe`s on the page?
- If my extension's `iframe` is blocked, is there a way for me to detect this?
- Any other reasons to avoid the use of `iframe`s in this scenario?

There are similar questions on the site, but they don't specifically ask what I want to know.

[The reason I want to use an `iframe` is this: My extension has to run independently of the website loaded (i.e. on any webpage). Its content script needs to show a UI for settings/help etc. Currently it does so by inserting a div into the page's DOM. However CSS from the webpage gets applied to the extension's UI, something which is harder to fix than one would think. Using an `<iframe>` seems to a way to avoid this issue.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, trying to sandbox your CSS from interference, when injecting into the DOM is very difficult without declaratively setting every known style attribute. It's a well documented problem and some solutions can be found in the following posts:

- [How do I prevent CSS interference in an injected piece of HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540927/how-do-i-prevent-css-interference-in-an-injected-piece-of-html)
- [Is there a way to "sandbox" an HTML block away from its page's CSS without using iframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529513/is-there-a-way-to-sandbox-an-html-block-away-from-its-pages-css-without-using)

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with dropping your UI it into an `<iframe>`. I'm not aware of any settings or extension that would block this behaviour.

If your framed UI needs to interact with the DOM on the parent page or a content script  you can do so with the use of [Window.Parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.parent). Also you may need to consider [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) if your pulling in the UI from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

Answers in order:

1. People [do not commonly use settings/extensions to block iFrames](https://superuser.com/search?q=title:iframe). Rather the opposite; the biggest complaint is how to get content out of iframes placed by ISP's and leach/wrapper sites, etc.
2. Yes, you can detect if your iFrame is blocked by having your iFrame's JS send an "I've started" message.  If the message is not detected, assume the worst. :)
3. No reasons to avoid iFrames, other than they are a bit of a PITA to work with.  If you just need to "show a UI for settings/help etc.", then it might be better to have your extension just open one of [the popup window types available to extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10340481/331508).  You control the HTML/CSS/JS of those completely without worry of interference by the page.