# Inserting a bar on top of every page on the web through browser extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm writing a browser extension that inserts a banner on top of every page that the user visits. The banner must not be sticky and must not block any existing content. ([my chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-facts/bjkhdklfbghoadcamlpmkafgmehcmima))

Currently I'm doing this by adding the banner content to the DOM through the following javascript in a contentscript that is inserted on every page:

```
$content = $('<div id="lb-banner'>blah blah</div>');
$('html:first').addClass('lb-banner-added').prepend($content);
```

I'm adding the content before body so that the banner is not affected by how the site is styled. Then, in order to push the main content of the page down while not affecting any potential site layout, I'm using the following styles:

```
html.lb-banner-added {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 32px;
}
#lb-banner {
   height: 32px;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: -32px;
   display: none;
   ... other styles...
}
.lb-banner-added #lb-banner { display: block; }
```

This pushes the whole html down while the banner is absolutely positioned to fill in the empty space (in this case 32px).

I have tried other methods to add the banner on top of every page. However this method is compatible with the most sites so far (even many of those with sticky headers).

However this is definitely not the best solution as I cannot get it working on facebook, twitter, linkedin (works but is blocking some content), gmail/gcalendar/gdoc (works but caused some contents to be moved outside of the window), and many more.
Furthermore, this method requires me to specify the height of the content, which is okay for now but I would prefer a more dynamic method.

---

**Notes:**

Without the styling I showed above, the banner would still appear on top of every page. However doing so will also break layout on many sites such as google.com. For example on Google, the banner will just cover the black nav bar and there will be extra spacing right before the search results.

Here's the chrome extension that is in question https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-facts/bjkhdklfbghoadcamlpmkafgmehcmima

Answer (score 3):

If you're injecting your UI directly into the DOM, it doesn't matter what you do, you can never completely sandbox it from unwanted interference. For example a given page may load in elements asynchronously after the page load, there's little you can do to prevent it from shunting your UI out of the way. Also unless you declare every CSS style explicitly for your UI elements, they can always be overridden by externally defined styles.

One common method used in browser extensions is to embed the UI into a frame and plant that right at the top of the DOM. It's not a pretty solution, but it will isolate your styling from unwanted interference.

[Is it okay to insert an <iframe> into the page's content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617261/is-it-okay-to-insert-an-iframe-into-the-pages-content)

Comment: I am aware that there will be no best solution. However are there better ones than the one i'm currently using to support more percentage of pages? I've thought about using iframes, but wrapping every page you visit in an iframe is just not viable at all.

Comment: There's simply no good way to accomplish what you are doing and make it work on every site. If you'd like to see how difficult this is, download a Conduit toolbar for Chrome and take a look at their code. They have to have different code for hundreds of websites, and there are still websites it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting you own css into a website can cause problems, if the things in your css code have the same names as other things in the website it will interfere, I would suggest using very unique names like "awesome-facts-bjkhd-lb-banner"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).